# Did Martian Manhunter actually gain five senses, if so, which ones?

Tags: dc, martian-manhunter

Back in January 2018, some fan asked Comic Book Resources about Martian Manhunter's nine senses, this number having been dropped in *JLA: Year One* #6 (1998).

[image: Martian Manhunter reveals he has nine senses]

> Wikipedia tells me that Martian Manhunter has 9 senses ("compared to humans"). What are those senses?! And does he ever even use them? Their source they refer to is JLA Year One #6. Thanks in advance!

CBR went on investigating the question; the whole story can be read [here](https://www.cbr.com/martian-manhunters-nine-senses/). Basically, it turned out that (unsurprisingly) the "nine senses" were just a throwaway line at the time of writing, but Mark Waid (the writer) played along, and CBR got the following list, including a bonus sense:

1. Taste
2. Smell
3. Hearing
4. Touch
5. Sight (all "common human senses" so far)
6. Martian vision (sees farther than regular vision)
7. Telepathy
8. Telekinesis
9. Empathic precognition
10. Molecular hypnosis

Flashforward to 2019 and *Justice League* #26, where Martian Manhunter is looking for Luthor in some house, and claims that while Lex might have shielded his mind, he has "fourteen other senses and they're all screaming to him that he's not alone".

[image: Martian Manhunter searching for Luthor]

That means Martian Manhunter has 15 senses in total. Barring telepathy, that's 14, and barring the other 9 we know of from the list above, that's five. **Is it known what those five other senses are?**

It's not impossible Martian Manhunter got some new abilities since the 90s; I just don't know which ones would count as senses. Of course it could just be a new throwaway line, but then again it'd be nice to have this confirmed and/or expanded on by James Tynion IV (the current writer), like Mark Waid did before him.

Comment: How are telekinesis and molecular hypnosis "senses"?

Comment: @Adamant because Mark Waid needed them to be? By reading the article it seems he just picked through MM's power list, and I do agree some are a stretch, but I guess what the writer says, goes

Comment: Of course humans have far more than 5: just off the top of my head, there's balance and proprioception.  So maybe he still has the same 4 "extra" senses, it's just that they're acknowledging 10 *human* senses.